# How can you get support candies in Magikarp Jump?

Tags: magikarp-jump

One of the Trainer Tips in Magikarp Jump says something to the effect of, "Once your berries are upgraded to a certain point, you may get support candies".  I noticed that at level 25 you get *one* support candy upon the 25th upgrade, but the tip suggested to me that you might get them at random or through some other mechanism; and further, the large numbers needed for various things suggest to me that there must be a better way than just getting a small number when winning certain league matches or the relatively rare upgrading a candy/training to 25 (which is very expensive).  I've played up through level 20 Magikarp (trainer level 10) and have only seen three support candies total.

I'm looking for a better way to get support candies, or a sense for how many you'll ever get.  So:

**What is the list of ways to get support candies?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Current

You can get candies the following ways:

- Reach a milestone in a league, i.e. Stage 5, Stage 10, etc.
- Upgrade a Food or Training level to 25/50/75/100
- Complete a level of the "Decorations Collected" and "Items Used" achievements
- 4% of the time from Charizard
- 65% of the time from "Event 4: Our Eyes Met...", when meeting the man's eyes
- Each time you earn 40,000,000 experience points after reaching trainer rank 100

---

### 1.2 and earlier

The above applies to 1.0-1.2 as well, except in 1.2, it was each 5,900,000 experience past rank 79, in 1.1, it was each 290,000 experience past rank 63, and in 1.0 it was each 40,000 experience past rank 51, plus the "Our Eyes Met..." event did not exist.

See also: [Serebii.net](https://www.serebii.net/magikarpjump/support.shtml)

Comment: FWIW, "Rarely" from Charizard is 4% ([source](http://www.serebii.net/magikarpjump/support.shtml#charizard))

Comment: At level 1.2 the max trainer rank is 79 and you get a support candy at much higher XP.

Comment: @JohnoBoy Yup, that's what the first paragraph is saying.

Comment: @JohnoBoy Though I've now incorporated it into the main body of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is 1.1 or earlier, but one of the Trainer Tips says this:

> If you increase the rank of your food items or training regiments to a certain point, you can get Support Candies as an extra bonus!

[image]

I haven't experienced this myself yet.