# How can you get Diamonds in Magikarp Jump?

Tags: magikarp-jump

Since we have another question on [How can you get support candies in Magikarp Jump?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310079/how-can-you-get-support-candies-in-magikarp-jump), it seems like a good idea to have one for Diamonds.

Diamonds are used for unlocking Support Pokémon and Decorations, but seem to be in very short supply - especially considering how freely Coins are given at higher ranks.

**What are all the ways to earn Diamonds in Magikarp Jump?**

Answer (score 6):

Here is a list of methods :

- Levelling up your Trainer Rank : 10 Diamonds
- Clearing League matches :

  - 10 Diamonds every 5th battle
  - 25 Diamonds for the League Champion
- Certain Events :

  - "All That Glitters" : 50% chance of 7 Diamonds
  - "Lost Luvdisc" : 4 Diamonds
  - "Name Rater" : 3 Diamonds, requires nicknamed Magikarp
- Sunken Treasure : 21% chance of 5 Diamonds

  - Treasure can be made to appear every 7 hours with Popplio's skill.
- Various Achievements :

  - Achieve achievements : 25 Diamonds at 10, 21, 34, 48 and 64
  - Number of Logins : 25 Diamonds at 3, 7, 12, 30; 50 Diamonds at 70
  - (Unique) Events Triggered : 5 Diamonds at 3, 10, 17, 26, 39
  - (Unique) Patterns Collected : 5 Diamonds at 1, 5, 10, 18, 29
  - Magikarp Fished : 5 Diamonds at 3, 10, 40, 90, 190
  - Social Media Shares : 5 Diamonds at 3, 10, 25, 50, 100
  - Number of Skill Uses : 5 Diamonds at 3, 20, 100, 300, 800
  - Magikarp Forced to Retire : 5 Diamonds at 1, 4, 12, 25, 70
- With the Diamond Miner, 100 Diamonds per day

  - The Diamond Miner costs 250 Tickets, which will set you back about £44.

If you know of any others, please feel free to update this answer.